# Duplicate with wrong answers?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

If a question was asked before but doesn't have correct answers, is that question still a duplicate?
If yes, are duplicate questions still found by the search function to find the correct answer?
If not, what should be done if the question was wrongly  closed?
Is this a reason for "in need of moderator intervention"?

I am asking because I stumbled across [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2107809/solving-the-functional-equation-fxy-fxfyy%E2%88%9Afx/2107879), yesterday.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Duplicate is duplicate.

If the older question is the same as a new question, **and the new question has no better answers**, then mark the newer as duplicate of the older, and if you can answer, post the answer on the original.

However, if the newer question already got answers which are better than the answers on the older question, do the opposite: close the older as a duplicate of the newer.

In the end of the day, what matters most is getting the best possible answers. So while duplicates should be closed, the order (newer vs. older) doesn't really matter.

Comment: Ok so in the case that the newer question already has a better answer than the old one and is still closed, it was wrongly closed? What can one do in such a case?

Comment: @LeBtz well, it depends. If you're really sure the answers on the newer are better, you can flag the question, choose "Other" and explain why it should be reopened. From quick look on your specific case, your answer got 2 upvotes, while the answer to the older question got +7. So not sure the site moderators will deem yours "better". All in all, if the questions are really the same, just answer the older question, and delete your answer to the newer.

Comment: This is a good solution, thanks. Will do that.

Comment: Cheers, and keep up the good contents there! :-)